# Why is the thread in the "start" method been put to wait in the below context?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, wait, procrun

I was going through an Apache Procrun tutorial and came across the following implementation for the start and stop methods of the service.

```
public static void start(String[] args) {
startThread();
synchronized (loggerThread) {
  try {
    loggerThread.wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    log("'Wait' interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
}

public static void stop(String[] args) {
if (loggerThread != null) {
  log("Stopping the thread");
  loggerThread.interrupt();
  synchronized (loggerThread) {
    loggerThread.notify();
  }
} else {
  log("No thread to interrupt");
}
}

private static void startThread() {
log("Starting the thread");
loggerThread = new Thread(new RandomLoggerService());
loggerThread.start();
}
```

When the start method is called, it calls the "startThread" method which will create a new thread and whatever is in its "run" method implementation would start executing. But why is the "loggerThread" synchronized on and why is it put to wait? And when I call the stop method it should notify the wait in start method right. So why is the execution logic handed over to start method again by the stop method? This is a little confusing, Please advice.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: btw, never use a Thread as lock; especially never `wait/notify` on it -- [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-)

Comment: It reads like a bug to me. Do not use.

Comment: You should never wait() without checking a condition in a loop.  This is because a) notify() can be lost if nothing is waiting and b) wait() can wake spuriously.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a thread **T1** that calls `start()` it will create a thread **T2** and start it through `startThread()`. **T1** now takes the lock/monitor on the `loggerThread` object and calls `wait()` on it. This will make **T1** "pause" and wait for any notifies on the monitor for `loggerThread`. If another thread (**T2** or any other) calls `loggerThread.notify()` it will wake up **T1** again so it can continue.

So, to be clear, **T1** is not controlling what is happening with **T2**, it's more the other way around. This however is something you should rarely be touching as synchronization can be done in much better (and clearer) ways.